# Get value of R, G, B by color

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I have user type the color (e.g. White, Red,...) so how can I get value of R, G, B with the color of user gave?

I have a function (float r, float g, float b) to set color a node. So i let the user type the color name they want, then i want to convert that color name to get r, g, b value for my function.

Comment: I have a function (float r, float g, float b) to set color a node. So i let the user type the color name they want, then i want to convert that color name to get r, g, b value for my function.

Comment: *"So i let the user type the color name they want"*  [Chartreuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartreuse_%28color%29), anyone?  Offer the user a [`JColorChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Color defines a *limited* number of enums representing basic colours. [This code excerpt](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/color_Str2Clr.html) uses reflection to map from their names to the RGB representations.

Other than that you'll have to maintain a map of colors/RGB values, or possibly a set of system properties, and use [Color.getColor(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getColor%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I have a function (float r, float g, float b) to set color a node. So i let the user type the color name they want, then i want to convert that color name to get r, g, b value for my function.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Map which contains all your optional colors as Strings together with their RGB representation (For the record, Color is found in the java.awt package):

```
Map<String,Color> colorMap = new HashMap<String,Color>();
        colorMap.put("white", new Color(255,255,255));
        colorMap.put("red", new Color(255,0,0));
```

Then use the text entered by the user to lookup your Color in the map:

```
String userColor = <whereever you get your string from>;
Color result = colorMap.get(userColor.toLowerCase());
```

Finally, use this Color object which has int values for RGB to retrieve the float values you need and pass them to your function:

```
yourFunction(Float.valueOf(result.getRed(),Float.valueOf(result.getGreen()),Float.valueOf(result.getBlue()));
```

If possible I would advise to use integers instead of floats for your RGB, as it will range from 0 to 255 in whole numbers in most if not all cases.

A good place to get all the colors you'd ever need with their RGB's is this website: http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Comment: The representation of a color channel as float, while maybe not inutitively so, offers 24 bits of precision (*per channel*). Just because the decimal representation looks inaccurate to you it doesn't mean it produces inaccuracy when the computer uses it. In fact the conversion int <-> float for 8 bit channel values is perfectly reversible.

Comment: I agree that it is more accurate, but do you have a logical name for every possible decimal value of a color? Because of the limited number of logical color names people actually use, I'd use integers in this case. Smaller, easier to read and produces a much more readable code as you can leave out all the parsing of Java's awt.Color int values to the respective float values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the color as a String you lookup this `Color` in a map and this will give you the Red, Green and Blue values.

Comment: I have a function (float r, float g, float b) to set color a node. So i let the user type the color name they want, then i want to convert that color name to get r, g, b value for my function.

Comment: You need to set the colour as well. You can store this information in a `Map<String, Color>` so you can lookup these values later. btw, normally each red, green, blue is a value between 0 and 255.